# Get MVC style route data (URL last word) with JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What I need is to be able to pull the route data out of the MVC URL. I found this solution on SO, however it doesn't suit my needs because I need access to two segments not just one:

```
var URL = "http://www.xzy.com/AMS/Audit/Agency/Blah";
var number = URL.match(/(\d+)$/g);
```

This regex code grabs the last segment `"Blah"`. How would I grab `"Agency"` as well? Considering the last two segments being words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\w+` to match a word. To make sure the word is the one right before the last, you can use a lookahead: `(?=\/\w+$)`.

```
var URL = "http://www.xzy.com/AMS/Audit/Agency/1A0A0A1A7A3A9A7";
var agency = URL.match(/(\w+)(?=\/\w+$)/g); // ["Agency"] 
var number = URL.match(/(\w+)$/g); // ["1A0A0A1A7A3A9A7"]
```

You could also use `RegExp#exec()` to get the value as string (not an array like above):

```
var URL = "http://www.xzy.com/AMS/Audit/Agency/1A0A0A1A7A3A9A7";
var matches = /(\w+)\/(\w+)$/g.exec(URL);
var agency = matches[1]; // Agency
var number = matches[2]; // 1A0A0A1A7A3A9A7
```

Check [**demo jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pRUN/) for both.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I should clarify, the second segment is a word as well..I just used that above as an example. I wasn't aware it would be different for numbers. Any idea as to how to grab them both if they are both words? Thx again!